# how to bounce a char in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I needed some help to bounce a character on my screen using the emu8086.
The screen size is (80x25 char). I have managed to move it diagonally but it doesn't bounce back.Instead it just goes straight on x axes after reaching the boundry (i.e 24th row) Here is what I have done until now.

```
enter code here
Data_seg segment 'data'
char db 'A' 
char2 db ' '
x1 db (1)
y1 db (1)
Data_seg ends

Code_seg segment 'code'
assume CS:Code_seg,DS:Data_seg

main PROC far
    mov ax,Data_seg
    mov ds,ax


    mov cx,40
   loop1: 
    ;gotoxy  
    mov ah,02
    mov dl,x1
    mov dh,y1
    mov bh,0
    int 10H

    ;print a
    mov al,char  
    mov dl,al  
    mov ah,02H
    int 21H

    ;gotoxy  
    mov ah,02
    mov dl,x1
    mov dh,y1
    mov bh,0
    int 10H       

    ;print " "       
    mov dl,char2
    mov ah,02H
    int 21H       

    inc x1       
    inc y1

    ;if(x1<2)||(x1>79)
    mov al,x1
    cmp al,2
    jl  ifPart
    mov al,x1
    cmp al,79
    jge  ifPart      


   ;if(y1<2)||(y1>79)
   y11:       
    mov al,y1
    cmp al,2       
    jl  ifPart2

    mov al,y1
    cmp al,24
    jge  ifPart2  ;jge for boundry(24)

    jmp endif             
                 ifPart:
                       dec x1
                       jmp y11

                 ifPart2:
                   dec y1

                 endif:


   loop loop1



    Code_seg ends
end main
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write the bouncing algorithm/logic in the code. At the moment your logic does [+1,+1] always and after reaching row 24 it will start to do additional [0,-1] to it (so the total change is (+1,+0)), then after reaching the 79 column it will do additional [-1,0], so the total change will be (+0,+0).

I.e., your code does what you did write there, there's no problem in the code.

To fix your logic, try to write the algorithm first in some plain language (English helps, when asking at SO), and turn that into simpler steps, until they resemble assembly instructions, write that as comment in your source, and implement each comment with few instructions.

For a start, you may want to have "move" vector, and add that to [x1, y1], instead of:

```
    inc x1
    inc y1
```

(i.e., `mov al,[moveX] add [x1],al` …and similarly for `y`).

Then when boundary is reached, negate that part of move vector, so it will flip from +1 to -1 and back. If your starting position is "inside", checking for boundaries after update is ok (0 || 79 triggering flip), if starting position can be on boundary too, you should rather try to do update, detect invalid position (-1 || 80), flip the vector, cancel invalid update, and do valid update.

Comment: The character is bouncing now, by moving the vectors. Theres a slight problem which occurs when it bounces back.It shows the character at the left most column of the 24th row and then bounce.

Comment: Fixed: I managed to fix the problem (described in the comment) by changing "cmp al,24" to "cmp al,23". The program is working perfectly now.Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @MUHAMMADAHMEDVOHRA about 24/23.. isn't the problem with your usage of DOS output interrupt, making the screen "scroll" when last line is used? Consider direct writes to VRAM (the text mode starts at B800:0000 by default unless you reconfigure the graphics card internals), which will be much faster, plus it will give you full control over VRAM content, so you can print all 256 VGA characters and use all possible color/blink combinations. And no scrolling at last line (you would have to do scrolling manually by code, either by moving VRAM content, or changing start of video memory).